# Hypothesis Testing and calculating p-value for Pandas dataset

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python, p-value, pandas

I want to study the relationship between car accidents and weather temperature.

So, I have a dataset for car accidents that have different attributes related to accidents and weather temperature for when the accidents occurred as follow:
[image]

To study this relationship, I want to formulate my hypothesis as follow:

- H0: There is no relationship between hot weather (greater than 28
  degrees Celsius) and the number of car accidents
- H1: There is a relationship between hot weather (greater than 28
  degrees Celsius) and the number of car accidents

I am not sure of how to calculate the p-value for the above hypothesis in python. I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

cd = pd.read_csv('Accidents.csv', parse_dates=['DATE'])

hot = cd[cd['Temperature Celsius']>28]
notHot = cd[cd['Temperature Celsius']<=28]

ttest_ind(hot['Temperature Celsius'], notHot['Temperature Celsius'])
```

How do I calculate the p-value for the above hypothesis? is my implementation correct by just getting the records that match my criteria and passing them to ttest-ind or I have to pass all the dataset instead of "notHot"?

or should I summarize the data using a different approach such as the number of accidents in each months compared to targeted weather temperature and perform different statistical test as follow:
[image]

I am a bit lost on how to choose the best statistical test and how to perform it. I am interested in the statistical significance of the effect of temperature on the number of accidents. So, is it better to calculate the statistical significance using the above hypothesis or using regression for example?

Thank you very much.

The sample dataset is available in the following link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WWtihWyUhL1m5Bp094SINTF14_icncnh